# How to set a DataGridView column to a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn?

Tags: c#, winforms

Here is my code:

```
DataSet data = new DataSet();
data.ReadXml("data.xml");

DataGridView grid = new DataGridView();

var genreCboBoxItems = data.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(genre => genre.Field<string>("genre")).Distinct().ToArray();

// TODO: Make is so the 'genre' column in grid is a combo box?

grid.DataSource = data.Tables[0];
grid.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
this.Controls.Add(grid);
```

*edit: genreCboBoxItems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:  (*not tested*)

```
var column = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

column.DataSource = data.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().
      Select(genre => new { genre = genre.Field<string>("genre") }).Distinct();
column.DataPropertyName = "genre";
column.DisplayMember = "genre";
column.ValueMember = "genre";
grid.DataSource = data.Tables[0];
// Instead of the below line, You could use grid.Columns["genre"].Visible = false;
grid.Columns.Remove("genre");  
grid.Columns.Add(column);
```

Comment: That definatley removed the column and re-adds one with a drop down, with the items added but the combo box is not set to it's underlying value.

Comment: Also, try setting both `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`. Updates my code.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/88afa087-62bb-4cf8-833f-8f9ca600c609) might help you cast DataGridViewColumn to DataGridViewComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

First create DataGridViewComboBoxColumn using designer with proper name. Then say you have a list of String list and other string values to bind to that datagridview then use this code:
Below code will bind a list to two DataGridViewTextBoxCell  and a DataGridViewComboBoxCell. Note AllCriterias is a list with two string values and a list of string. DGVEligibilityCriteria is the grid name.

```
for (int i = 0; i < AllCriterias.Count; i++)
            {
                DataGridViewTextBoxCell Cmb1 = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)DGVEligibilityCriteria.Rows[i].Cells[0];
                Cmb1.Value = AllCriterias[i].Name;
                DataGridViewTextBoxCell Cmb2 = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)DGVEligibilityCriteria.Rows[i].Cells[1];
                Cmb2.Value = AllCriterias[i].Type;
                DataGridViewComboBoxCell Cmb = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)DGVEligibilityCriteria.Rows[i].Cells[2];
                foreach (var filtervalue in AllCriterias[i].FilterValues)
                {
                    Cmb.Items.Add(filtervalue);
                }
             }
```

Need to display the fist index as default by setting selectindex property. 
Use this code : Here "filterValues" is the name of the DataGridViewComboBoxCell which u created in the datagridview designer.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow  row in DGVEligibilityCriteria.Rows)
            {
                row.Cells["filterValues"].Value = (row.Cells["filterValues"] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items[0];
            }
```